# Django Rest Framework slug_field error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have this serializer and model. I want to show in my API the field *username* of **User** model, but I receive this error.

> AttributeError at /api/v1/client_share_requests/1/
>
> 'Profile' object has no attribute 'username'

***serializers.py***

```
class ClientShareRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    checked_by = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        queryset=Profile.objects.all(),
        slug_field='username'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ClientShareRequest
        fields = ('checked_by')
```

***models.py***

```
  class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')

  class ClientShareRequest(models.Model):
        checked_by = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True,
                                            related_name='checked_by')
```

I try to access the User model instance like this:

```
   checked_by = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        queryset=Profile.objects.all(),
        slug_field='user.username'
   )
```

but I receive this error:

> 'Profile' object has no attribute 'user.username'

Thanks for helping. (Sorry for my English :P)

Comment: Try `user__username`.

Comment: @RahulGupta doesn't work `'Profile' object has no attribute 'user__username'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is DRF does not allow nested attribute lookups on SlugRelatedFields. Simple workaround would be to add a username property on the Profile model and use this in the serializer:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')

    @property
    def username(self): 
        return self.user.username

class ClientShareRequest(models.Model):
    checked_by = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True,
                                            related_name='checked_by')


class ClientShareRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    checked_by = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='username'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ClientShareRequest
        fields = ('checked_by', )
```

This works for reads :)

Comment: It works for get request, but when you want to do post request on that model (`ClientShareRequestSerializer`) then it will not work as property is somehow not mapped there.