# Getting AttribueError by SlugRelatedField despite the object being saved

Tags: python, django

I am creating an API to save class teachers. Now all the fields in the ClassTeacher model are foreign fields so I am using a SlugRelatedField in the serializer. It looks like SlugRelatedField does not support attribute lookup like this "user__username" and raises attribute error HOWEVER the object is still being saved.

> models.py

```
class ClassTeacher(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class_name = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school_id = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

> serializers.py

```
class ClassTeacherSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    teacher = SlugRelatedField(slug_field='user__username', queryset=Teacher.objects.all()) <---- this is causing the error
    class_name = SlugRelatedField(slug_field='class_name', queryset=Classes.objects.all())
    school_id = SlugRelatedField(slug_field='school_id__username', queryset=School.objects.all()) <---- and I am assuming that this will too

    class Meta:
        model = ClassTeacher
        fields = '__all__'
```

I tried adding a `@property` in the Teacher model to retrieve the username and use the property in the slug_field but that did not work too.

How can I save the object without getting the error?

EDIT 1:

> teachers/models.py

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    photo = models.URLField()
```

> teacher/serializers.py

```
class TeacherSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = '__all__'
```

> school/models.py

```
class School(models.Model):
    school_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo = models.URLField()
```

> school/serializers.py

```
class SchoolSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = School
        fields = '__all__'
```

EDIT 2:

Here's how I used the `@property` by referring from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215208/django-rest-framework-slug-field-error):

> teacher/models.py

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    photo = models.URLField()

#Here's the extra property part
    @property
    def username(self):
        return self.user.username
```

> classteacher/serializers.py

```
class ClassTeacherSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    #Here I changed user__username to just username as mentioned in the above link
    teacher = SlugRelatedField(slug_field='username', queryset=Teacher.objects.all())
    class_name = SlugRelatedField(slug_field='class_name', queryset=Classes.objects.all())
    school_id = SlugRelatedField(slug_field='school_id__username', queryset=School.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = ClassTeacher
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Please provide the model Teacher implementation also

Comment: @Someprogammer I have made the edits. Take a look now.

Comment: Hello @AyushGupta DRF does not allow nested attribute lookups on SlugRelatedFields

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Yes I figured that too but what would be the alternative?

Comment: you can use  @property to get relations

Comment: @AnkitTiwari I already tried that (see the lines before edit part) but still no success

Comment: how did you tried can you give one sample example because it worked for me

Comment: @AnkitTiwari I have made edit 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `@property` for example

```
class User(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    photo = models.URLField()
    
    @property
    def get_username(self):
       return Teacher.objects.filter(user_id=self.id)
```

and than inside your `ClassTeacherSerializer`  use `slug_field='username'`

let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

try renaming serializer field from teacher to user and using slug_field='username'

Comment: would you please elaborate because the serializer field from the teacher model is already named user?? I will include the serializer for the teacher and the school both.

Comment: change field name from ClassTeacherSerializer.teacher to ClassTeacherSerializer.user, it should work;
if you want to add teacher as a direct field, i'd try to .annotate() it in the get_queryset() view method or write a custom ClassTeacherField (see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields)

Comment: the problem, likely, is that it tries to find a relation in your model named "teacher" and it cannot find it, because there is no such field in a model, only "user". Another solution is to change "user" to "teacher" in model. In my opinion, the best one